# Error installing "Statsmodels"

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, statsmodels

I am not able to install "statsmodels" package through Pycharm. I tried command line installation as well, which still did not work. I am using Python 3.X version. Please could you help. I need the package direly. Sharing the installation error as well.[image]

Thnx in adv.

Comment: Post the error message here instead of linking to its screenshot.

Comment: I figured a way out. Installed an older version of of the package. That worked.